# Get outbound IP range azure website PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, web, azure-web-app-service

Is there anywhere powershell command to get all outbound ip addresses for azure websites ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
(Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroupName" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceName "webAppName").Properties.outboundIpAddresses
```

Comment: Could you please format your answer with code tag ? just to be more readable.

Comment: Minor issue with a missing closing " but other wise the exact answer I was looking for. `(Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "resourceGroupName" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites -ResourceName "webAppName").Properties.outboundIpAddresses`

Comment: Sorry all- I didn't get the notification in time. Next time I will be sure to put it in a code block!

Comment: This will not work when you have Az and AzureRM installed on the same machine. It worked fine from Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 1):

There is no powershell command to get the outbound IP addresses, however you can still get them with the new portal.

New portal-> all settings -> properties> shows 4 outbound IP Addresses

The 4 addresses are not dedicated to your website, they are per scale unit. All websites hosted on the same scale unit will use these same 4 addresses when making outbound network calls. While you site stays on the same scale unit these IP addresses won't change. If at some point your site gets relocated to a different scale unit (and you will receive an advanced notice prior to that happening) then the IP addresses will change.

Comment: This answer is (at least at this time) incorrect. Neal Ganslaw provided the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Az module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/) to do this:

```
$application = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $applicationName
$application.OutboundIpAddresses
$application.PossibleOutboundIpAddresses
```